# Why do they use interface in this guide

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

So I am pretty new in Java and I'm trying to get started with web applications using JSP and servlets. I've came across this CRUD web app guide [A simple CRUD Tutorial Using Java Servlet / JSP](https://programmingenthusiast.wordpress.com/2015/05/02/a-simple-crud-tutorial-using-java-servletjsp-and-mysql/). The thing is, I don't understand why they have to create the StudentDAO interface. I know this would be easy as pie to understand for most of you that's why I'm asking here. All I want is an answer if StudentDAO interface is really needed since we only declare the methods there, and override all of them in a class called studentDAOImplementation anyway.
I know I should read some more about Java interfaces but I was hoping to get explanation on why interface is needed in this example.

Comment: Usually in small apps a lot of things aren't "needed."  However a [DAO is a standard pattern,](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97423/are-there-any-real-benifits-to-a-dao-layer) so they're trying to teach you to use one, because in larger apps it [could be useful there.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97423/are-there-any-real-benifits-to-a-dao-layer)

Comment: Interfaces allow you to have multiple different implementations of the same thing. It means that if they decide to swap to MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server in the future then they can swap out the implementation without recompiling everything else.

This leads into things like **dependency injection** and **inversion of control** which are very interesting and you should learn them.

Answer (score 1):

This does not really have a simple answer. The sketch of the answer would be - because you want to be independent of how your application actually stores/retrieves the data in the database. The interface provides the *functional specification* of what the DAO (Data Access Object) should be able to do - it is up to the specific implementation to actually do it. For example, for testing purposes, you might want to setup a stub DAO that does not really use the database, but instead gives you prefabricated objects. In a real-world complex application, you might want to vary the DAO depending on what database engine is really used and so on and so on. So generally, this is an instance of decoupling the functional specification from the implementation.